# Best practice for using certificates (.pem) files in a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, certificate

i'm learning docker/k8s; I want to pass/store a .pem file to my boostrap container which runs on a k8s cluster. This container uses the .pem to create a k8s secret (kubectl create secrets ...) which will be used by the other apps running on k8s by mounting the kubernetes secrets.

I can think of the following options,

- I can pass the .pem details as ENV to the container.
- I can build the image with the .pem file.
- I can store the .pem file in S3 and download it from within the container.

Wanted to understand which of these is the best practice/secure method to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen it done in multiple ways but I would suggest using a config map so that then the pem file lives inside your k8s cluster and you don't have to deal with encryption within s3 and such. Also this allows your devops team to handle the maintenance rather than the app developers if you include this within the docker code

[Config Map Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

1. Create the config map

   ```
   kubectl -n <namespace-for-config-map-optional> create configmap ca-pemstore — from-file=my-cert.pem
   ```
2. Add new config to your pod yaml file

   ```
    apiVersion: v1 
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: <some metadata name>
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: <container name>
          image: <container image>
          volumeMounts:
          - name: ca-pemstore
            mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/my-cert.pem
            subPath: my-cert.pem
            readOnly: false
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          command: ...
          args: ...
        volumes:
        - name: ca-pemstore
          configMap:
            name: ca-pemstore
   ```

Comment: Thanks Edward, but this is exactly what my bootstrap container does... it creates the k8s secrets via the .pem file and that is then mounted by the application. My question is what is the best practice to pass the .pem to the bootstrap container ?

Comment: @nevosial So is the issue that you are trying to figure out how to create the pem file dynamically? e.g a github action that creates the pem file, and then creates configmap for usage?

Comment: Edited the question. I have the .pem file too. i need to pass it to the bootstrap container which will create the k8s secret. I'm just trying to understand the best way to pass the .pem file to the bootstrap container.

Comment: What is bootstrap container? Are you talking about init container? To get this clear in my head you have a file(.pem) from which you create a secret(k create secret --from-file) and this secret is mount as something(env or volume) in a second container? If you look into Init containers. Their purpose is to prepare the environment for the application before the application start to run.

Comment: @Zambozo So init containers are related to a particular app/pod where it can be defined so that the pod has the required resource..... However, the secret that this bootstrap creates is a generic one to be used by any subsequent pods in the k8s cluster. However, i think the question is valid for an init container as well... what is the best way to pass the .pem file to the init container ?

Answer (score 3):

(Although one could say that K8S Secrets are type of Config map). 
I think that the **better approach is to use K8S Secrets (over Config maps)** like specified in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-tls
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  # the data is abbreviated in this example
  tls.crt: |
        MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
  tls.key: |
        MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7yn3bRHQ5FHMQ ...
```

Then you can create a [pod that has access to the secret data through a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        # name must match the volume name below
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /etc/secret-dir
  # The secret data is exposed to Containers in the Pod through a Volume.
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: secret-tls
```

(*) In this specific example the `tls.crt` and `tls.key` will be created under `/etc/secret-dir`.